# Countifs Date is between two dates Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a cell A with the date of the beginning of the calendar week and a cell B with the end of the calendar week.

No I want to count all the rows from a different sheet that contain a date within this calendar week.
I have tried the following but it returns an error because it can't parse the formula.

```
=COUNTIFS('Other Sheet'!$H$1; >A2; 'Other Sheet'!$H$1; <B2)
```

Any advice?

Comment: Okay, so what I have found now is that you have to put the operand in "" in a countif statement. 
Which gives me this: 

=COUNTIFS( 'IMPORT: Metasheet'!$H$1:$H; ">"&A2; 'IMPORT: Metasheet'!$H$1:$H; "<"&B2)

No error. Now everything returns "0", but at least the formula seams to be right.

Answer (score 8):

Okay, so here is what worked:

1. You have to make sure the operands are in "" and there is a & before the relative cell reference.
2. You have to make sure all the date cells are formated as dates.

Then this formula worked:

```
=COUNTIFS('Other Sheet'!$H$1:$H; ">"&A3; 'Other Sheet'!$H$1:$H; "<"&B3)
```